# Can a company use private Slack conversations for a lawsuit against you?

Tags: united-states, defamation, workplace

Can a company use private Slack conversations for a lawsuit against you? I work at a company where there's a lot of toxicity and a lot of people seems to be unqualified for their jobs, which leads to a very high turnover. 15 people left over the span of a year. And I did mention to some people that some people seem to be highly unqualified from experience. I am wondering if that can be used against me somehow even if I said what I felt was the absolute truth. I don't think it's necessarily a defamation case, but I don't see what other reason I might get sued for.

Comment: They may not decide to sue you, but they can certainly come up with "reasons" to fire you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a company use private Slack conversations for a lawsuit against you?

It depends on whether the circumstances and the parties to the conversation imply that the conversation is covered by something like the attorney-client privilege.

*Statements of opinion* are not actionable, but false *statements of fact* are. The terms of your expression(s) are relevant for ascertaining whether the statements are of fact even if framed/disguised as opinion.

If you have evidence that your statements are truthful, the counterparty is unlikely to prevail even if your expressions are statements of fact.

Answer (score 2):

Unless obtained illegally, a private Slack conversation is admissible evidence if it is relevant, in any kind of lawsuit. Even if it is obtained illegally, in a civil case it may still be admissible as evidence and a balancing test between the harm of the illegality and the contribution the evidence would make to discerning the truth of a material issue applies and it isn't automatically inadmissible as evidence.

Whether it would be relevant, and to what, depends upon the nature of the lawsuit and the overall facts.

Comment: In most jurisdictions, illegally obtained evidence may be admissible in criminal cases too. The US is an outlier in having a blanket prohibition.

Comment: @DaleM I totally agree and that observation was U.S. specific.